# Вывод массива на странице

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, views

Здравствуйте. Нужно вывести данный на страницу. 
Используется Yii2. Не знаю как реализовать вывод массива на странице(как написать правильно вьюху). 
Код контроллера:

```html
 public function actionFull()
    {
    $model = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM USER')->queryAll();
    return $this->render('full',['model'=>$model]);
    }
```

Возвращаться будет массив.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View-файл должен называться `full.php` и находиться в папке `/views/[имя контроллера]/full.php` вот простейший код реализации этой вьюхи

```
<?php
var_dump($model);
```

кстати, удалите `if (` из Вашего кода

Comment: Во. Спасибо. )
Просто когда копировал, то там было через условие, проверял, так ли сделал запрос к бд.